# LWUIT 1.5 Table - horizontal spanning layout

Tags: java-me, tablelayout, lwuit

I am wondering if this is a bug or just my faulty code. I've been trying to render table with some horizontal spanning. This is how it should look like:

[image]

In LWUIT 1.4 everything worked correctly. Since 1.5 the table looks like:

[image]

My implementation:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"", "", "", ""}, new String[][]{
                {"Header", null, null, null},
                {"1", "2", "3", "4"},
                {"1", "2", "3", "4"},
                {"String", null, "String", null}});


Table tab = new Table(model, false) {

        protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, final int column, boolean editable) {
            Component c = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
            c.setFocusable(false);
            return c;
        }

        protected TableLayout.Constraint createCellConstraint(java.lang.Object value, int row, int column) {
            TableLayout.Constraint tlay = super.createCellConstraint(value, row, column);
            if (row == 0 && column == 0) {
                tlay.setHorizontalSpan(4);
                tlay.setHorizontalAlign(Table.CENTER);
            } else if (row == 3)) {
                if (column == 0) {
                    tlay.setHorizontalSpan(2);
                    tlay.setWidthPercentage(50);
                } else if (column == 2) {
                    tlay.setHorizontalSpan(2);
                    tlay.setWidthPercentage(50);
                }
            } else if (row != 0) {
                tlay.setWidthPercentage(25);
            }
            return tlay;
        }

    };
```

Comment: hi, How to remove the border lines in table model. I used (Tabel table.getStyle().setBorder(null);). It remover border lines only, not cell border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug (in LWUIT) is triggered by the `tlay.setWidthPercentage(50);` which you can remove and still get the expected result. It seems the width percentage value doesn't take spanning into consideration which I'm guessing it should.

You should file a bug for this in the issue tracker, thanks for the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works better without tlay.setWidthPercentage(50). Table structure is well rendered, but width percentages are inexact.

Comment: Try setting the margin/padding of everything to 0 to make sure that none of these are getting in the way. Since percentages are used (not pixels) we can't guarantee 100% accuracy which doesn't make much sense when targeting multiple device resolution. However, if its noticeable then please file an issue in the issue tracker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added this line

```
TableLayout.setDefaultColumnWidth(1);
```

before

```
Table tab = new Table(model, false) {
...
```

and it worked out.

Comment: by the way, I tried to find out what's the difference but "ver 1.4" is removed from svn repository)